# BizTalk Setting up a recive location and port using the HL7 Adaptor

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, hl7, btahl7

Just installed BizTalk 2010 and the HL7 adaptor,  trying to set up a proof of concept application through the admin console:

1)Created a new 'Demo Application'
2)Created a request/response receive port 
3)Created a request/response receive location associated to the receive port
  3.a) Set the Type to MLLP
  3.b) The only options I see for the Recieve pipeline are:
    PassThrueReceive
    XMLRecieve
  3.b) The only options I see for the send pipeline are:
    PassThruTransmit
    XmlTransmit

How do I get the BTAHL7X and BTAHL7XML receive/send pipeline components to appear as an option?

I've tried adding a reference to BTAHL2XMLPipeline.dll and BTAHL72XPipeline.dll but I get an error:

> Failed to add resources to application.
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=47400&ProdName=Microsoft+BizTalk+Server+2010&ProdVer=3.9.469.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn.Properties.Errors&EvtID=AddFilesForm_AddFailed&EvtChain=Microsoft.BizTalk.ApplicationDeployment+%2cApplyMultipleResourcesAddError%3bMicrosoft.BizTalk.ApplicationDeployment+%2cSatEntryExists
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Failed to add resource(s). (mscorlib)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=47400&ProdName=Microsoft+BizTalk+Server+2010&ProdVer=3.9.469.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.BizTalk.ApplicationDeployment&EvtID=ApplyMultipleResourcesAddError&EvtChain=Microsoft.BizTalk.ApplicationDeployment+%2cSatEntryExists
>
> ---
>
> Resource (-Type="System.BizTalk:BizTalkAssembly"
>   -Luid="BTAHL72XPipelines, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35") already in store.  1) Use BTSTask's
>   overwrite flag or  2) Set redeploy flag to true in BizTalk Project or 
>   3) Click overwrite all checkbox in Admin MMC   to update if the
>   resource exists in the specified target application
>   "DemoApplication1". Overwrite flag will be ignored if the resource is
>   associated with another application.
>   (Microsoft.BizTalk.ApplicationDeployment.Engine)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=47400&ProdName=Microsoft+BizTalk+Server+2010&ProdVer=3.9.469.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.BizTalk.ApplicationDeployment&EvtID=SatEntryExists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your new application, do you have a reference to the default application?

From the BizTalk Administration Console, **Right-Click** on the application and choose **Properties...**. In the Properties screen, choose **References**. You will want to add a reference to the default application here.

If you do have a reference to the default application, has the adapter been registered?

From the BizTalk Administration Console, **expand Platform Settings** and then **right-click** on **Adapters**. Select the **New > Adapter...** option and then look for **MLLP** in the dropdown. Select **MLLP** and give it a name of **MLLP** and then select **OK**. At this point, you should have the MLLP adapter available for use.